# How to fix google cardboard sdk rotation bug?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

In unity3d using google cardboard sdk (0.5.2 version), CardboardMain prefab in unity3d project. I get random auto resets, when head rotation resets randomly to start position.

I can rotate it in 180 degrees and then wait and it randomly resets. Or moving and again it resets, each ~5 seconds.

How i can fix that? When i track rotation using webVr or this third-party sdk version https://github.com/JScott/cardboard-controls there are no problems, everything works fine, it is only official google sdk problem.

Disabling drift correction does not affect this bug.

Comment: Which phone is having this problem?  I have heard of this elsewhere, and it seems to happen on particular models only.